# How to find a child widget of certain type by context in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a Statefull/Stateless widget I need to check if the widget contains certain type of widget as its child.

Example:

```
Statefull Widget -> Container() => Column() => [Text(), Expanded() -> ListView()]
```

Here I need to check if the Statefull widget consists ListView() through its context...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [byType](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/CommonFinders/byType.html#:%7E:text=byType%20method%20Null%20safety&text=Finds%20widgets%20by%20searching%20for,be%20a%20subclass%20of%20Widget.) method.

This will find widgets by searching for widgets with a particular type.

So in your case, you'll have something like this:

```html
expect(find.byType(ListView), findsOneWidget);
```